# I am trying to hide keyboard after search click from keyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, background, keyboard, searchbar

I am trying to hide keyboard after search button click on keyboard but on click it start searching but after click it will close with `SearchBar`

I am using following snippet on search button click.

```
[Searchbar resignFirstResponder];
```

Another question is that i want to set background image for searchbar like below.
[image]

Comment: try [self.view endEditing:YES];

Comment: ya i have tried that code but same problem occure it will hide my searchbar

Comment: i want to only hide that keyboard

Answer (score 0):

you can set the background image . For more info: see this [tutorial](http://www.cyberdandy.com/how-to-get-rid-of-uisearchbars-background-and-customize-its-searchfields-background/)

From the doucmentation:

Customizing Appearance

> backgroundImage

Property

> The background image for the search bar.

Declaration
**SWIFT**

```
var backgroundImage: UIImage?
```

**OBJECTIVE-C**

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) UIImage *backgroundImage
```

Discussion
Images that are 1 point wide or stretchable images are stretched, otherwise the image is tiled.

Availability
Available in iOS 5.0 and later.

Comment: when i set any image in background image streched

Comment: and other question i cant remove search bar background which is behind of textbox

Comment: what is the image actual size?

Comment: 640 X 88 Pixel for search Bar Background

Comment: that is too bif gor a search bar. You have to reduce the image size.

Comment: I added a tutorial link,please look at it @hardikvyas

Answer (score 0):

this is delegate method you can call

```
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)sBar
{
    [sBar resignFirstResponder];

}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer friend but it will close my searchbar also